# Uncaught TypeError: .unshift is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a quite trivial piece of code that has me stuck.

With the following piece of code I'm trying to add a value to the start of the array which is the current first value minus 100.

```
var slideHeights = null;
// ... other stuff, nothing is done to slideHeights
function updateHeights() {
    slideHeights = $('*[data-anchor]').map(function(i, item) {
        return Math.floor($(item).offset().top);
    }); // [2026, 2975, 3924, 4873, 5822, 6771, 7720, 8669, 9618]
    slideHeights.unshift(slideHeights[0] - 100);
    slideHeights.push(slideHeights[9] + 100);
}
```

And I'm receiving the error

> Uncaught TypeError: slideHeights.unshift is not a function

If I comment the `.unshift` and correct the index in the `.push` all works fine and the 9th element is added correctly.

I even tried separating the value, but with no luck:

```
var x = slideHeights[0] - 100;
slideHeights.unshift(x);
```

I'm really stumped on this, it must be a trivial problem I'm not seeing.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance for your replies.
Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jquery's `map` doesn't return native array, you need to use `get()`

```
slideHeights = $('*[data-anchor]').map(function(i, item) {
    return Math.floor($(item).offset().top);
}).get();
```

Or use [toArray](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)

```
slideHeights = $('*[data-anchor]').map(function(i, item) {
    return Math.floor($(item).offset().top);
}).toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. :) Although I wonder why does `.push()` work?

Comment: @GigiSan If you have got this error *Uncaught TypeError: slideHeights.unshift is not a function*, then i doubt if push is working on next line since after this error is thrown next line wouldn't have got executed at first place.

Comment: I commented the .unshift and reduced the index in the .push and it works. [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/118494/)

Comment: @GigiSan Yes, I am surprised as well. There is no mention of push being supported in jquery's documentation at all. http://api.jquery.com/?s=push

Answer (score 1):

If anyone got this error who are new to JavaScript, make sure your spelling is right.

> `Array.unshift()` does not follow camelCase.

So it would be `Array.unshift()` instead of `Array.unShift()`